# Combine two datasets in SSRS Reporting Services and count

Tags: reporting-services

I have two datasets - In dataset 1 `MedAdministration` I have `Medical_Condition`.  In dataset 2 `ProblemList` I have `Medical_Condition`.  I want to combine both datasets and count.

For instance Heart attack may be in dataset 1 and in dataset 2.  I just want the report to show Heart Attack 20 which would be a combination of both datasets and the total from both into one total on the report.

I have tried the lookup function and the join, but I keep getting errors.

```
=Lookup(Fields!Medical_Condition.Value,Fields!Medical_Condition.Value, "ProblemList")
```

> "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The Value expression for
>   the textrun ‘Medical_Condition.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ has an
>   incorrect number of parameters for the function ‘Lookup’.    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2005Impl.SetReportDefinition(String
>   Report, Byte[] Definition, Guid batchId, Warning[]& Warnings)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2005Impl.SetReportDefinition(String
>   Report, Byte[] Definition, Warning[]& Warnings)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2010Impl.SetItemDefinition(String
>   ItemPath, Byte[] Definition, String expectedItemTypeName, Property[]
>   Properties, Warning[]& Warnings)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.SetItemDefinition(String
>   ItemPath, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]&
>   Warnings)

I can't even get it to combine the data, let alone count it.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!
Tara

Answer (score 0):

Lookup function takes 4 parameters:
Lookup(source_expression, destination_expression, result_expression, dataset)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on SuperSimmer's answer, you'll need to use the correct lookup parameters within your expression to add the two.  I don't know for sure how the report is laid out, but for example, if you need values summed for `Heart Attack`, you'll need a count of that field from each dataset and add those together.

```
 =Count(IIF(Lookup(Fields!Medical_Condition.Value,Fields!Medical_Condition.Value, Fields!Medical_Condition.Value, "ProblemList") = "Heart Attack", 1, Nothing)) 
+ Count(IIF(Lookup(Fields!Medical_Condition.Value,Fields!Medical_Condition.Value, Fields!Medical_Condition.Value, "MedAdministration") = "Heart Attack", 1, Nothing))
```

If you'd prefer a dynamic result or if the 'Condition' is provided from a parameter, you'd replace the `"Heart Attack"` with `Parameters!Condition.Value` to check each dataset for the value provided.

Comment: Thank you.  This is very helpful.  I'd like for it to list each medical condition from each dataset but as one "title" with the total of both.  There could be 50 different "conditions".  As an example it would have the title Medical Condition and in the columns underneath list each condition with the totals combined of each condition.  I'm also using a from to date parameter and want to break it down into months.  I think I have that part figured out. :)